# Implementing TypeConverter for handling PropertyGrid exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I 'm developing a WinForm application and use of a PropertyGrid control. To handle exceptions form PorpertyGrid I implemented a class derived from TypeConverter and overwrote various methods including the ConvertFrom where I check if you can convert, for example, string to integer, and show a MessageBox if not. The problem is that the ConvertFrom is called multiple times when writing an incorrect value in a property and therefore the MessageBox is displayed several times. Any idea why it happens or how can I solve it?

```
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    if (value is string)
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(value as string, out result))
            return result;
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
    var def = context.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    return def != null ? def.Value : 0;
}
```

Comment: How would a TypeConverter know what an incorrect value is?  That sounds like data validation.

Comment: It doesn't know. When ConvertFrom is called the paramater value is a string that should represent an integer, if it doesn't, the MessageBox is shown and a default value is returned. But the method is called several times. @Plutonix